# How to use field value to set custom class and apply it to a html element in node.html.twig without using attributes and addClass()

Tags: theming, 9

I have tried to apply my custom class to an image tag

I have set classes for it

```
{% set imgClass = [
        'img-shape-' ~ (node.field_image_animation_shape.value|clean_class)
      ] %}
```

and have tried to apply to image as attributes

```
 attributes.addClass(imgClass)
```

that is renders all attributes for the node which duplicating on main node div so i need to avoid using attributes...
How do i do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply create your own attributes. Read [[Documentation] Using attributes in templates](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/using-attributes-in-templates). It's much easier to maintain in the long run. Especially if you start to use conditions to add or remove attributes.

> This provides a new blank Attribute object to use to build up attributes.
>
> ```
> {% set my_attribute = create_attribute() %}
> {%
>   set my_classes = [
>     'kittens',
>     'llamas',
>     'puppies',
>   ]
> %}
> <div{{ my_attribute.addClass(my_classes).setAttribute('id', 'myUniqueId') }}>
>   {{ content }}
> </div>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I have workaround this without using attributes and that how i did it:

```
 {% set imgClass = node.field_image_animation_shape.value|clean_class %}
```

created variable from the list text field - used key value for it

and then printed in hard way in to image classes

```
<img class="img-fluid img-shape-{{ imgClass }}" src="..." />
```

and this is result :

[image]

hope it will help to anybody :)